# I want to get an array on all the parent ids of an id

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a table that have 3 columns. `id, parent_id and text`. I want a function that returns all `parent id` of an `id`..

[image]

Suppose that I pass a parameter `4` which is the `ID`, the array should return `4,3,2,1` because 3 is the parent of 4, 2 is the parent of 3 and similarly, 1 is the parent of 2.
How can I achieve that?

I have tried this so far. But this is returning arrays..

```
function getTree($id){
    $arr = array();
    $parent = mysql_query("SELECT parent_id FROM task WHERE id = '".$id."'");
    $parent_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($parent);
    if ($parent_query['parent_id']==0){
        echo "This is the parent";
    } else {
        $arr[] = $id;
        $arr[] = $parent_query['parent_id'];
        $arr[] = getTopTree($parent_query['parent_id']);
        echo '<pre>';
      print_r($arr);
      echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Just to be curious but have you read [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) already?

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Comment: Can you make it  more clear? I

Comment: Did you heard about recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom function of your own like as

```
function checkParentIds($id, $data = array()) {
    $parent = mysql_query("SELECT parent_id FROM task WHERE id = '$id'");
    $parent_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($parent);
    if ($parent_query['parent_id'] > 0) {
        $data[] = $parent_query['parent_id'];
        checkParentIds($parent_query['parent_id'], $data);
    } else {
        $parent_result = (empty($data)) ? 1 : implode("','", $data);
    }
    return $parent_result;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Just one thing. I want the `id` itself to be the part of string. How do I do that?

Comment: If I pass `4` as `id`, I should get `4,3,2,1` instead of `3,2,1`

Comment: Before if condition simply use `$data[] = $id;`

Comment: I used this code but it is returning `10,5,4,3,2,1,1`. 1 is repeating twice at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, group_concat(parent_id) as parents, test <yourtable> group by id;
```

and then in php you can just explode an appropriate column of retrieved row:

```
// ... retrieving all the rows stuff
$parentsIds = explode(',', $row['parents']);
```